# Conditional and absolute convergence of the integral depending on the parameter

Tags: improper-integrals, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

How to determine values of $p$ making the integral

$$\int_{x=2}^{\infty}\frac{(x+1)^{p}\sin(x)}{\log(x)}\mathrm{d}x$$

converges absolutely or conditionally? Comparison $\log(x)$ with $x$ where $x\to\infty$ gives divergence for $1-p<1$. Am I right and what to do next?

Comment: it is absolutely convergent for $p<-1$

Comment: @kmitov comparison test?

Comment: Yes. sin(x) is bounded.